# Calculate Fibonacci Serie in Prolog, Tail Recursive

Tags: prolog, fibonacci, tail-recursion

I want to calculate Fibonacci Series in Prolog,in recursive tail mode.

```
fibonacci(0,0).
fibonacci(1,1).
fibonacci(N,Result) :-
   fibonacci(N,1,0).

fibonacci(N,Result,Count) :-
   Count < N,
   !,
   Count1 is Count + 1,
   Result1 is  Result + Count,
   fibonacci(N,Result1,Count1).  
fibonacci(N,Count,Count).
```

but the result is incorrect,what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line `Result1 is  Result + Count` you only add the Count  the variable Result and add 0,1,2,... but in fibonacci you need to add two previous e.g 0,1,(1+0=1),(1+1=2),.... 
I suggest this implementation:

```
fib(0, 0).
fib(1, 1).
fib(N,Result):-fibonacci(N,0,1,Result).

fibonacci(0,N,_,N).
fibonacci(N, Prev1,Prev2,Result):-
   N>0,
   New_Prev2 is Prev1+Prev2,
   N1 is N-1,
   fibonacci(N1,Prev2,New_Prev2,Result).
```

Comment: Awesome job! :)

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging words!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tail recursive solution.You need to use an accumulator. Essentially you are calculating fibonacci backward. When you get to 1 you stop.

```
fibonacci(0,0).
fibonacci(N, Result):-
   N > 0, 
   fib(N,0,1,Result).

fib(1,_,Accum, Accum).
fib(N,Val,Accum,Result) :-
   N1 is N-1,
   AccumNew is Val +Accum, 
   fib(N1, Accum,AccumNew,Result).
```