# Prolog tail recursion for Fibonacci sequence

Tags: prolog, fibonacci, tail-recursion

I have been trying to make a Prolog tail recursion for Fibonacci sequence, but I have a lot of trouble making the code, this is kinda what I was doing and I'm not sure if I'm going the right path

```
fibonacci(X,S):-
    fibonacci(X,1,S).

fibonacci(1,R,R).
fibonacci(2,R,R).
fibonacci(X,R,S):-
    X>2,
    X1 is X-1, 
    X2 is X-2,
    R1 is R,
    fibonacci(X1,R1,S1), 
    R2 is R1+R,
    fibonacci(X2,R2,S2).
```

I tried changing the code a bit and was even able to make the program in normal recursion, but not in tail recursion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Fibonacci Serie in Prolog, Tail Recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059986/calculate-fibonacci-serie-in-prolog-tail-recursive)

Comment: Also: [Efficient Fibonacci in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296917/efficient-fibonacci-in-prolog).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

The first two elements in a Fibonacci sequence are special. After that,
everything follows a regular pattern. Use a helper predicate that carries the extra state you'll want:

- the previous two values, and
- the current position within the sequence

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% fibonacci(Index,Value)
%
% where
% 
% - Index is the ordinal position with the sequence, relative to 0, and
% 
% - Value is the value of the sequence at that index.
%
% For instance,
%
% fib(  0,  1 ).
% fib(  1,  1 ).
% fib(  2,  2 ).
% fib(  3,  3 ).
% fib(  4,  5 ),
% fib(  5,  8 ).
% fib(  6, 13 ).
% fib(  7, 21 ).
% fib(  8, 34 ).
% fib(  9, 55 ).
% 
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
fib(0,1) .                              % the initial element in the sequence is special,
fib(1,1) .                              % as is the next element, but
fib(N,V) :- valid(N), fib0(1,1,2,N,V) . % all subsequent element follow the same pattern.

valid(N) :- integer(N) -> N > 1 ; var(N) .

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% 
% fib0( Prev1, Prev2 , Ctr, Index, Value ) .
% 
% "private" helper predicate to tail-recursively compute the fibonacci sequence,
% 
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fib0( P1 , P2 , N , N , S ) :-              S is P1+P2 .
fib0( P1 , P2 , C , N , S ) :- C1 is C+1 , P3 is P1+P2 , fib0(P2,P3,C1,N,S) .
```

Comment: `0` is not the first/zeroth element of the canonical Fibonacci sequence: `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, . . .`. And the element at index 2 relative to zero is `2`, not 1.